# How to generate page links in mvc view (API method is already returning paged results)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm completely new to MVC and Web API so apologies if this question doesn't make sense...

I'm consuming a Web API search method, passing in variables `startIndex`, `_pageSize` which returns the pagesize list of records and a `totalCount` of records (example json below). I have a table in my mvc view page which is displaying the return data and the total count.

```
{
    "errors": [],
    "result": {
        "fileCount": 30,
        "infoList": [
            {
                "fileId": "7dcaf6b2-d97b-4234-8a33-344484375f09",
                "integratingApplicationId": "6775bd47-00b5-4864-9f42-5b6ef9d69837",
                "applicationDescription": "SSIS letter",
                "createdDate": "2019-06-12T11:01:39.03",
            }
}
}
```

In my mvc view I would like to add links for the pages so the user can navigate to the next or previous page (or the page numbers), just wondered what is the best way to do this? Do I need to add pagination logic in my controller or can I use JavaScript in the view to generate the links?

Comment: Does your JavaScript Code know the current `startIndex`? If yes, you can just set a request with `startIndex+=_pageSize` AND `_pageSize=_pageSize` (So basically the same). Then just rerender the page.

Comment: This jQuery plugin is very useful for pagination: https://st3ph.github.io/jquery.easyPaginate/

Answer (score 0):

you can do both, easiest is to just build your pagination using something like a partial view and populate it before you send it to the view. In this situation, you wouldn't need to do anything on the front end.

Either way, it's very easy.

Think of this way, what do you need to be able to build the pagination?
You need to generate some links which will look something like this:

`blabla/morebla/data?indexPage=index` where index is whatever page number you want to display. You need to know the range of that index, from 1 to whatever.

You have the page size, let's say it's 20. You have data which tells you that you have 30 records. You will therefore need 2 pages to display the data so you create the hyperlinks with index 1 and 2. You can easily come up with a formula to decide how many pages you need. You divide your records size ( 30 ) to page size ( 20 ) and if the mod of this is higher than zero then you add 1 to the pageIndex.

something like this:

`int pageTotal = ( recordsCount / pageSize )` you take the int result of that ( in your case 1 ) and if the modulus of this operation is higher than 0   ( which it is ) then you add 1 to the page count and thus you get two. You need a second page to display the last 10 records of your data.

All that's left now is to build the links in a foreach loop so in this case you'll get two, as you already calculated the **pageTotal** :

```
blabla/morebla/data?indexPage=1
blabla/morebla/data?indexPage=2
```

Careful how you send the indexes to the API, your index 1 on the UI might be index 0 actually on the API side, but you want to display 1 on the UI just from a usability point of view, so you might have to do a bit of adjustments in your code to account for that.

You don't need any plugins and you can do it on back-end side or front-end side, whichever you are more comfortable with.